# ListView doesnt refresh while deleting in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, refresh

I have a `ListView` which is to bind to an `ObservableCollection`. When i delete items manually (per button event), the items are getting removed and the `ListView` gets refreshed immediately.

When i delete the items in a for *loop*, only the list is getting refreshed at the end of the operation, after all elements are deleted. Before the items are getting deleted, there are some time-consuming operations on them and also notification to the user in another `ListView`.

So how can it be achieved, that the list gets refreshed after every single deletion of an item.

The question is not, how to delete items in a loop from an list, because this works (in reverse order). The question is, why is the UI not refreshing while deleting the items.

Here i have simplified sample code, which is showing this behaviour:

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LstFiles}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Content="Los" Name="losBtn" Click="losBtn_Click" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Content="del" Name="delBtn" Click="delBtn_Click" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# behind**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListViewTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> LstFiles { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LstFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                LstFiles.Add(string.Format("file_{0}", i));
            }

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private  void losBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = LstFiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                LstFiles.RemoveAt(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }   
        }

        private void delBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LstFiles.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The sleep is for simulating the time-consuming operations.

Comment: I dont't think so, because i remove items already in reverse order.

Comment: So you want to refresh your list view on UI, after removing every item from your list?

Comment: Correct. The behaviour should be the same, like clicking the "del" Button in my example.

Comment: `LstFiles.Clear();`

Comment: So what's preventing you from refreshing/rebinding your list view every time when you remove an item from your list?

Comment: @SeM: So how do i refresh/rebind the list correctly?

Comment: @Marco Refresh/rebind is nonsense, because you are already using an ObservableCollection. You simply must not call Thread.Sleep. See my answer.

Comment: @Clemens the sleep is only in this example code. In the real app there is no sleep, but there are for example file operations (reading, deleting, writing) which will consume time.

Comment: @Marco Then call them asynchronously, either by awaitable I/O methods, or by wrapping them in `Task.Run()`.

Comment: @Clemens can you modify your example to work with Task.run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the ui not refreshing while deleting the items

This is because you are calling `Thread.Sleep()`, which simply blocks the UI thread. You must never call that in a UI application.

While it's unclear why you want to have this "delete loop" at all (instead of just clearing the ObservableCollection), you may use `Task.Delay()` instead of Sleep in an `async` Click handler method:

```
private async void losBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = LstFiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        LstFiles.RemoveAt(i);
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }   
}
```

If instead of a simple delay there is some time-consuming operation to be invoked, you may simply wrap that in a `Task.Run` call:

```
private async void losBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = LstFiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        LstFiles.RemoveAt(i);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // some long running operation
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ok, now im getting the foolowing exception, wehen removing: ````    This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread````

Comment: Sure, you must of course not access any UI elements or bound properties from the Task. It's hard to tell what exactly you should change, because you did not show us your actual code in your question.

Comment: Ok, i will check my code. Proberly i have to rewrite it with an mvvm pattern.